# Цикл выводит только первый элемент

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть переменная group_photo_Albums,возвращает album_id,которая должен передаваться следующей функции, но цикл берет только первое значение, и тупо зацикливается на первом значении album_id:

-Первая переменная group_photo_Albums:

```
 group_photo_Albums=get_json("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getAlbums",
             {'owner_id':-group_id, 
              'count':count, 
              'offset':offset, 
              'need_system':1,  
              'access_token':access_token, 
              'v':5.73})

group_photos_items=group_photo_Albums['response']['items']

while True:
    for item in group_photos_items:
        id_Album=item['id']
        ids_Albums.append(id_Album)

    for album in group_photos_items:
        print(album['id'])
    photos_in_group=get_json("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get",{
            'owner_id':-group_id,
            'album_id':album['id'],
            'access_token':access_token,
            'v':5.73})
```

В ответе выводит только первый id из функции с group_photo_Albums. Посоветуйте что делать?

Comment: Странно, что на первом. Судя по коду должен на последнем...

Comment: Что делать: начать с более понятного описания проблемы. В коде нет функции с  group_photo_Albums,  а в тексте она упоминается.